# Returning a character string from a function.... restrictions?

Tags: c++, c, string

I was wondeirng I have this particular parcel of code

```
char* usage()
     {
         static char errors[] = {"Sorry Invalid Option entered\nPlease Enter an appropriate option"};        
         return errors;
     }
```

I've called the function properly and it does what I want it to. However as Soon as I do this...I get a plethora of errors.

```
char* usage()
     {
         static char errors[] = {"Sorry Invalid Option entered\n
                                 Please Enter an appropriate option"};        
         return errors;
     }
```

All I did is put the second line one row below I get errors. Now, All i'm wondering is what is the difference between the two? I seemingly have the same argument entered into both character arrays. Is it due to the fact I did not malloc space for the array?

Comment: Do you want all those spaces in the string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C and C++ do not support multi-line literals that way, but you can use this:

```
char* usage()
{
     static char errors[] = {"Sorry Invalid Option entered\n"
                             "Please Enter an appropriate option"};        
     return errors;
}
```

note the additional quotes!

Comment: To add: This works because the preprocessor concatenates adjacent string literals into one. (Adjacency of course ignoring whitespace.)

Comment: Ahhh I see. So thats just something specific to C++. Thank you!

Comment: @PresidentRFresh: It's also valid for C, I clarified the answer.

Comment: @PresidentRFresh: Hey, I just met you, and [this is crazy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qTIGg3I5y8), but here's my answer, accept it maybe? ;)

Answer (score 5):

In C (I don't know about C++) you can write strings in several lines by using the fact that quotes concatenate the strings (this concatenation is done by the preprocessor)

```
char test[] = "one " "two" " " "<= that's a space :)" "\n"
              "three and four\n"
              "five etc and so on\n"
              "\n"
              "for ever and ever ...\n";
```

*Note: no semicolons except on the last line.*

Comment: Thanks I had no idea about this.